# Php mysQli script with AND operator not working as expected

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep writing queries that seem to never work the way I want them to. In this script, if the user who tries to login has `user_level 'Admin'` he should be direct to `adminhome.php` elseif user has `user_level 'Employee'` he should be directed to `employeehome.php`. I've created these two users Amanda with `user_level Admin` and Hugo with `user_level 'Employee'` to test the script but no matter who i'm login with, it fires `$error`.

**login.php**

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = $_POST['password'];          


    $hashedPasswordQry = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername'";

   $userLevel = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE username='".$myusername."'");

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$hashedPasswordQry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword, $row['password'])) && $userLevel  == 'Admin') {

        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;


        header("location: user/adminhome.php");

    }elseif($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword, $row['password'])) && $userLevel == 'Employee'){

           $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;


        header("location: user/employeehome.php");
    }
else{
     $error = '<h5 style="text-align: center;" class="alert alert-danger" >Your username  or password is invalid</h5>';

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using two select queries to the same table with the same where clause for two different columns? In case you weren't aware, you can pull multiple columns from a single query `SELECT password, user_level`...

Comment: @cteski: alright thanks mate. It works.

Comment: @cteski: you want the cred or... I leave my own answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and drop an answer if that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two very similar selects, when one is only necessary. You can select multiple columns in a query by separating them with a comma `SELECT this_column, that_column FROM ...` And while you were executing both queries, you're only accessing the results of the password query and not the `$userLevel` result. A more correct version would look like:

```
$query = "SELECT password, user_level FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword, $row['password'])) && $row['user_level']  == 'Admin')
{
    // do stuff
} elseif ($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword, $row['password'])) && $row['user_level'] == 'Employee')
{
    // do stuff
}
```